"Manage route tables" on Endpoint in VPC disabled
I'm getting timeout errors connecting from Lambda to Secrets Manager and S3. The Lambda is inside a VPC to connect to RDS.
I created two Endpoints, one for Secrets Manager and one for S3. Both Endpoints are in the same VPC as the Lambda and have all subnets associated with them and have the same Security Groups associated.
I read that I need to manually add the Endpoints to the route table but "Manage route tables" under Actions is disabled.
What causes "Manage route tables" to be disabled?
Is the routing likely what I'm missing or is that likely not the problem anyways?



I've never tried doing that using that menu option. When you add a VPC endpoint the route is typically added for you, if you use the console, I haven't done that using CloudFormation in quite a while but I think you'd have to do it for yourself. Simply go into the VPC route table and make the entries required.
